# How to enable and disable a Vim syntax script?

Tags: css, vim, plugins

I'm using the [css_color.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2150) plugin to highlight CSS hexadecimal color codes with the actual color. It's a bit distracting to have the highlighting turned on all the time so I am wondering if there is any way to toggle a syntax plugin on and off.

Comment: Just so everyone's clear, you want to unload the css_color plugin, not just disable *all* syntax highlighting, i.e., via `:syn off`, right?

Comment: yes, but :syn off turns off all syntax highlighting, i just want to disable the one plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create new syntax instead.

Put the file in `.vim/syntax/css_color.vim` and add `runtime syntax/css.vim` at the top.  Now it acts like its own syntax definition that happens to inherit the base CSS syntax.

When you want CSS with smart colors, use `:setf css_color`.  When you want to back to stock CSS, `:setf css`.

---

edit: To bind a key:

```vim
function! ToggleCssColor()
    if &filetype == 'css'
        setf css_color
    else
        setf css
    endif
endfunction

noremap <Leader>c :call ToggleCssColor()<CR>
```

Then <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will switch between the two styles in normal mode.  You can set the key to whatever you want, use `inoremap` to bind a key in insert mode, etc.

Comment: thanks it works perfectly. Do you know how i would map a single key to toggle this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at alternative plugins. I use [colorizer - Highlight #rrggbb or #rgb color](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3567), because it has advanced features, works not just for CSS, and can be turned on/off easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the other [Colorizer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3963) [plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3567). They have a toggle function and in generally work better and load faster in terminal vim.